# Accessing a database running in docker container from the internet

Tags: docker, configuration, database

I have an application running inside a Docker container in Azure, running as an App Service. The application uses a MimerSQL database that is inside the same container as the application.

I would like to be able to access the database port (1360) from my desktop to look inside the database for debugging purposes but I have not discovered a way to reach it from the outside.

If I run the Docker container on my desktop I have no problems as I can supply the "-p" directive and hence map the database port to a port accessible from my host (or any other computer, for that) but I have so far not been able to find a similar directive in Azure to expose the port to the outside world, neither as 1360 nor as anything else.

I was thinking about mapping the database to a web port but the application uses the https port for a status message so that one is gone.

Comment: i would suggest to use a vpn/pptp access to your instance it will solve a lot of issues and is setuped in less as 10 minutes

Comment: @djdomi, sounds like a plan. The problem is that I have no idea how to set up a VPN to the container. Would that not require for instance access to port 22, which I thought is blocked?

Comment: normally you have access on the ohysi al server/vm and sofsr you can install there the vpn, you can find good tutorials with google

Comment: @djdomi: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. What does "ohysi", "al" and "sofsr" mean? Those are not words I understand.

Comment: physical and sofar